# Google AdWords ads are disapproved because "destination not working"

Tags: google, googlebot, advertising, google-ads

We have been having an issue setting up adwords for one of our clients and despite multiple phone calls to Google we cannot get an answer out of them as to why our ads are being disapproved.

[image: Screenshot1]

Initially there was no robots.txt file set up but we asked the Website developer to do this. Still no results

There are no errors in webmaster tools and when running the site through the following tool (and others like it) there are no issues
https://www.prepostseo.com/ping-domain-from-multiple-locations

Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this issue or would this be an issue on Google's end?

Comment: Use Google Fetch & Render. Furthermore... not related to your question I will add that the ad in terms of ad performance is bad since the destination is low value (no content) which will equal a bad scoring, therefore, costing your customer more per a click. Also no need to repeat Freerangechef as a sibling in the display URL, Google scoring takes keywords out of the domain name which you have.

Comment: Also it is generally better than you make a landing page dedicated to Auckland Catering with the display url /auckland-catering/... Pointing ads all to the home page is generally a poor idea because it is harder to get users to perform a goal, which ultimately is why your paying money on the ad. A dedicated page, easier to steer them to a goal (contact form/telephone) etc. I generally use homepage for adword campaigns with the branding. Just my 2 cents, opinionated comment.

Comment: In regards to the Disapproved, I recommend that you ring them. They are normally very good on the phone with problems such as this.

Answer (score 2):

This is so simple it happens to me a lot of times, The simple solution is that put / at the end of the URL.

**means freerang.co.nz/**

and put lowercase URL in display URL
freerangchief/catering

Also, your description is not matching with title